# How to add custom style to paper-icon-button

Tags: polymer-2.x

I have the following code:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{todos}}" sort="sortComparator">
                <div class="row">
                        <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-forward"></paper-icon-button>
                    <span>{{item.name}}</span>
                    <span class="btn-set">
                        <paper-icon-button icon="delete" on-tap="deleteTodo">delete</paper-icon-button>
                        <paper-icon-button icon="star" on-tap="toggleFavorite">star</paper-icon-button>
                    <span>
                </div>                              
            </template>
```

I want to add a color yellow to `icon="star"` if `item.isFav` is true. But i am not able to find a way to do it. Any suggestion, how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

**give id for the button**

```
<paper-icon-button icon="star" id="myButton" on-tap="toggleFavorite">star</paper-icon-button>
```

by using the id you can set the style for it now

```
this.$.myButton.style.color = 'yellow'
```

Comment: paper-icon-button is inside dom-repeat template. When i use this.$ it gets dom-repeat element. How to get paper-icon-button inside dom-repete.